# Windows Form C# dateTimePicker (it only gets date and not time)

Tags: c#, web-services, datetime, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I am building a Windows Form web service app and I have 2 dateTimePicker. The first one its for the start the and the second one its for the end date.

In the dateTimePicker format I have set it to Time. When I select any date from the start or end date, the date change but the time does not change.

I need the date and any time that I will chose within the application.

Here you have the 2 variables how I have set the dateTimePicker

```
DateTime startDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
DateTime endDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have to remove the date after the value.

Thanks anyways